# Custom Ubuntu 16.04 Plymouth script doesn't work

Tags: boot, grub2, themes, plymouth

Help!

I followed some tutorials to change my boot splash image (the plymouth loaded image) and am stuck now.

Here's my 'mysplash.plymouth' file:

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=MySplash
Description=Wallpaper only
ModuleName=script
[script]
ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/mysplash
ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/simple/mysplash.script
```

And here's my 'mysplash.script' file:

```
num = Math.Random()*10 + 1;
select = Math.Int(num);

if (select == 1)
 splash_image = Image(“ck.png”);
else
 if (select == 2)
  splash_image = Image("k.png");
 else
  if (select == 3)
   splash_image = Image("np.png");
  else
   if (select == 4)
    splash_image = Image("ok.png");
   else
    if (select == 5)
     splash_image = Image("pa.png");
    else
     if (select == 6)
      splash_image = Image("pl.png");
     else
      if (select == 7)
       splash_image = Image("r.png");
      else
       if (select == 8)
        splash_image = Image("vs.png");
       else
        if (select == 9)
         splash_image = Image("w.png");
        else
         if (select == 10)
          splash_image = Image("z.png");

screen_width = Window.GetWidth();
screen_height = Window.GetHeight();
resized_splash_image = splash_image.Scale(screen_width,screen_height);
wallpaper_sprite = Sprite(resized_splash_image);
wallpaper_sprite.SetZ(-10);
```

And finally, here's an additional 'mysplash.grub' file that I copied from the default ubuntu theme:

```
if background_color 0,0,0; then
  clear
fi
```

Now, I have all the files required in one folder as shown below

```
foo@bar:/usr/share/plymouth/themes/mysplash$ l
ck.png  mysplash.grub      mysplash.script  ok.png  pl.png  vs.png  z.png
k.png   mysplash.plymouth  np.png           pa.png  r.png   w.png
```

But still the boot splash image is standard black. Also, if I test the theme using:

```
sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; for ((I=0; I<10; I++)); do sleep 1 ; sudo plymouth --update=test$I ; done ; sudo plymouth --quit
```

The spinner theme is shown (a part of plymouth-themes package).

So, the question is, "**How do I make it work?**"